# How can I solve the Unexpected EOF error in react-native and nodejs for the following code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, express, fetch

This is the api that I created in node express.

```js
router.get("/out", (req, res)=>{
    res.cookie("jwt", "",{
        maxAge: 1 
    });
    return res.send({status: true, details: "logged out successfully"});
});
```

I am using fetch to call the api from react-native code as follows

```js
const handleLogOut = () => {
    console.log("Logging out");
    fetch(`http://ca946d24a8f1.ngrok.io/api/login_auth/out`,{method: 'GET'})
        .then((response) => response.json() )
        .then((responseJson) => {
            console.log(responseJson);
            if(responseJson.status === true) {
                navigation.navigate("Login");
            } else {
                alert("Something went wrong!");
            }
        })
        .catch((error) => console.error(error))
}
```

Whenever I try to make request, I get logged out but with

```sh
error:JSON Parse Error: Unexpected EOF.
```

But when I delete the line:

```js
res.cooke("jwt", "",{
    maxAge: 1 
})
```

from the code, the error is solved.

I want to know whats wrong and how can I solve this problem as I need to expire the cookie as well.

Comment: Please share your api endpoint file. Possible that you might not have exported the router Example : module.exports = router. Also try to use exception handling (try, catch block) in your api to catch errors to debug and resolve them.